# clingo: separate answer set atoms with newline

Tags: clingo

I'd like to know if there is an easy possibility to separate the predicates within an answer set by a newline instead of spaces. Example:

```
node(1..3).
```

called with

```
clingo path.lp
```

gives

```
clingo version 5.4.0
Reading from .../path.lp
Solving...
Answer: 1
node(1) node(2) node(3)
SATISFIABLE
```

But I would like to have this output

```
clingo version 5.4.0
Reading from .../path.lp
Solving...
Answer: 1
node(1) 
node(2) 
node(3) 
SATISFIABLE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I call

```
clingo path.lp --out-ifs=\\n
```

instead of

```
clingo path.lp
```